# Rails openssl X.509 certificate generation returning PEM?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, openssl

So I have a method that looks like this:

```
def self.generateNewSignedCert(csr, uId)
    # CSR = certificate signing request
    # filename = uId + '.pem'

    # csr = OpenSSL::X509::Request.new File.read Rails.root.join('keys','csr',filename)
    # raise 'CSR can not be verified' unless csr.verify csr.public_key

    ca_cert = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new File.read Rails.root.join('keys','certs','ca_cert.pem')
    ca_key_pem = File.read Rails.root.join('keys','certs','ca_key.pem')
    ca_key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new ca_key_pem, 'ning'

    csr_cert = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new
    csr_cert.serial = 0
    csr_cert.version = 2
    csr_cert.not_before = Time.now
    csr_cert.not_after = Time.now + 2592000

    csr_cert.subject = csr.subject
    csr_cert.public_key = csr.public_key
    csr_cert.issuer = ca_cert.subject

    extension_factory = OpenSSL::X509::ExtensionFactory.new
    extension_factory.subject_certificate = csr_cert
    extension_factory.issuer_certificate = ca_cert

    extension_factory.create_extension 'basicConstraints', 'CA:FALSE'
    extension_factory.create_extension 'keyUsage',
      'keyEncipherment,dataEncipherment,digitalSignature'
    extension_factory.create_extension 'subjectKeyIdentifier', 'hash'

    csr_cert.sign ca_key, OpenSSL::Digest::SHA1.new

    filename = uId + '_cert.pem'
    open Rails.root.join('keys','certs',filename), 'w' do |io|
      io.write csr_cert.to_pem
    end
    return csr_cert
end
```

the `csr_cert` that is returned to the controller is in the PEM format?

I have another method that generates a CA Cert, that looks almost the same, saves the file as a PEM and returns ca_cert and that works fine (returns the certificate, not the PEM)

Any one know why I'm getting a PEM instead of the cert back?

Some further info:

**Controller**

```
def newCert
    csr = CertificateAuthority.newCSR(session[:uID].to_s)
    @cert = CertificateAuthority.generateNewSignedCert(csr, session[:uID].to_s)
    render :layout => false
end
```

If I add `puts csr_cert` after the `extension_factory` lines it still prints out a PEM?

Comment: "Any ideas?" - about what? You don't really ask a question.

Comment: OpenSSL (and presumably Ruby) are using RFC 1424, which is PEM encoding for the certificate services. I believe RFC 2986 provides certificate services in DER encoding. You can convert certificates between PEM/DER with OpenSSL's `x509` utility. Look at `inform` and `outform` switches. There's also a `req` utility, but I don't know if it will allow the conversions.